# Replace multiple character with a single character

Tags: r, string, replace

I have this string

```
 string <- c("oxalic......R", "gentamicin....C", "penicilin.....R")
```

I would like to get this

```
string_changed <- c("oxalic - R", "gentamicin - C", "penicilin - R")
```

Trying

```
string_changed <- str_replace_all(string, pattern="\\.", replacement="\\{1}-")
```

But it replace all dots

Comment: Try : `sub("\\.+", " - ", string)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(string, "[.]+", " - ")
#[1] "oxalic - R"     "gentamicin - C" "penicilin - R"
```